# Не работает код в C++

Tags: c++

75/(1.8*1.8) = 23.148

При выполнении переменная BMI в консоль выводит 0.00032,а в дебагере значение равно 
-9.2559631349317831e+61

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>


using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::ios_base;

int main()
{

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    cout << "\t\t***BMI***\n\n";
    double BMI,Height,Weight;

    cout << "Введите рост в метрах и вес: ";
    cin >> Weight >> Height;

    BMI = Weight / (Height * Height);

    cout << "ваш BMI: " << BMI;

    _getch();
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спорим, я могу объяснить, откуда берется число `0.00032`?

```
1.8 / (75 * 75) = 0.00032
```

---

```
cin >> Height >> Weight;
```

---

> а в дебагере значение равно -9.2559631349317831e+61

Потому что Вы смотрите на значение этой переменной, остановившись на строчке

```
BMI = Weight / (Height * Height);
```

то есть - до выполнения вычислений.